# Problems with nested recyclerview

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, kotlin, nested

I have a nested recyclerview which should look like in the [image: picture].

I implemented it according to [this helpful site](https://manticarodrigo.com/nested-android-recyclerview-kotlin/).

The problem is, that I sometimes have a user with hundreds of items and in that case, it takes half a minute to open the activity.

I have a room database in the backend with two linked tables with foreign keys (users and items) and I select all users to get a user/item list where the items are a list in the user-table.

class userWithItems: (id: Int, name: String, ... ,List)

and I create the inner recycler view with the List of items in the adapter.

Would it be better to make one List UserItems (userid:Int, username:String, ... itemid:Int, itemList) and group them for the outer rv.

Or is there a possibility to get rid of the nested rv and make the design with just one recyclerview-list?

Or is there another solution to make the nested recyclerview work even if there are many items for a user?

code for the adapters:

```
// Code in Activity: (oncreate)

val recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.rv_users)
val adapter = UserAdapter(this)
recyclerView.adapter = adapter
recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, PassIntViewModelFactory(this.application, online_id)).get(MainViewModel::class.java!!)
mainViewModel.userList.observe(this, Observer {
    it?.let {
        adapter.setUserList(it)
    }
})
```

data class UsersWithItems(

```
    val id:Int, val username: String, val address, // fields from user table
    val items: List<Items>   // list of items for current user
```

)

data class Items (
        val id: Int, val itemtext: String, val itemlocation: String, val image: String // ...
)

// UserAdapter (outside)

class UserAdapter internal constructor(
        context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
private var userList = emptyList<UsersWithItems>()

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val username: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name)
    val num_pos: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_num_pos)
    val address: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_addr)
    val rv:RecyclerView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_user_items)
}


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val myItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_row_user, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(myItemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = userList[position]
    holder.username.text="${current.user?.username}"
    holder.num_pos.text="${current.items?.size}"
    holder.address.text = "${current.user?.address}"

    val adapter = UserItemAdapter(holder.rv.context)
    adapter.setItems(current.items!!)
    holder.rv.adapter = adapter
    holder.rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(holder.rv.context,LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false)

}
internal fun setUserList(userList: List<UsersWithItems>){
    this.userList=userList
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
override fun getItemCount() = userList.size
```

}

class UserItemAdapter internal constructor(
        context: Context
) : RecyclerView.Adapter() {

```
private val inflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
private var itemList = emptyList<Items>()

inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val itemtext: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_text)
    val itemlocation:TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_location)
    val image: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    val myItemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rv_row_user_items, parent, false)
    return MyViewHolder(myItemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val current = itemList[position]
    holder.itemtext.text="${current.itemtext}"
    holder.itemlocation.text = current.itemlocation
    if (current.image.length>0) {
        val image = Base64.decode(current.image, 0)
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.size)
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
internal fun setItems(items: List<Items>){
    this.itemList=items
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}

override fun getItemCount() = itemList.size
```

}

Comment: Sorry - I did not think that the code would be the big problem, but the concept, since it works fine with only a few items in the inner adapter.

Comment: I think that the problem is, that in the inner recyclerview every single item is created immediately even if there are 1000 items and one can only see 5 or 6 on the display and this takes its time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E. Reuter i have been through this situation the thing is the approach is quite correct by using nested Recycler View. Your code seems to be good. but the queries which you are using to query database. I think you should use queries in Background or on the other threas and show result as you get them instead of querying it from OnCreate or from main thread. Because getting this many items in one go can possibly create lag to activity and decreasing performance. try this out if you have not yet and let me know. What happens. Thanks...

I am editing my answer. the other thing you could do is if you have more than certain amount of items then instead of getting them at the first you should use some thing like pagination to load certain amount of items at once to avoid this lag.

Here i am attaching the code to query certain amount of data per load....

```
SApp.database!!.resultDao().loadAllUsersByPage(5, 10)
 @Query("SELECT * FROM Result LIMIT :limit OFFSET :offset")
 fun loadAllUsersByPage(limit: Int, offset: Int): List<Result>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer. I think that paging is really a good approach. But I cannot add the pageing directly since I am getting my data from a roomdatabase like this:

```
@Query(SELECT * FROM users)
fun getData(): LiveData<List<userWithItems>>
```

and the actual items are added by room because of a relation between user and items I will have to change this behavior.

I will try something like

```
@Query(SELECT * FROM users)
fun getUserData(): LiveData<List<Users>>
```

and then try to add an LiveData observer in the outer recyclerview to get the items in a separate query which uses paging.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. When I thought about pagination it came into my mind that the problem could be that the inner recyclerview has a height of wrap_content and so it needs to build all of the items and makes the rv useless. When I make the height of the inner rv 250dp, it works quite even with 2000 items.

So now I just have to figure out a way to always find the optimal height for the inner rv and solve the scrolling problem but the original problem is solved.

Special thanks to Aman B!